# Flexslider adding extra space to right of final slide…

Tags: jquery, flexslider

I’m running into an issue with Flexslider adding extra white space after the final slide.

I have created a 702px-wide div meant to display two 342px-wide slides at a time, with 18px between each. I’ve set the 'itemWidth' to '360px' to allow for the extra space and the 'itemMargin' to '0'.

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(window).load(function() {
      $('.flexslider').flexslider({
        animation: "slide",
        animationLoop: true,
        itemWidth: 360,
        itemMargin: 0
      });
    });
</script>
```

This gives me the proper spacing I need between slides but adds an additional 18px at the end that I cannot for the life of me get rid of. Even more annoying, it treats it like a fourth sliding transition when it should only need three.

Here’s a screen grab: http://bit.ly/XHJVeU

Note the four dots at the bottom. It should only need three to show four slides.

I have tweaked every bit of CSS I can think of but still no luck. Even adding padding/margin to the images does nothing. Frustrating.

Either way. I’m hoping someone has run into this before and that it’s a quick fix.

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE: HTML included for reference.

```
<div id="carousel" class="flexslider">
<ul class="slides">
    <li><img src="images/suite-a_01.png" /></li>
    <li><img src="images/suite-a_02.png" /></li>
    <li><img src="images/suite-a_03.png" /></li>
    <li><img src="images/suite-a_04.png" /></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Tough to include it all since it’s referencing the Flexslider jQuery slider file for various attributes. Added HTML above.

Answer (score 2):

Inspect the live output of your flexslider and check out the pagination bar(it's an  with class "flex-control-nav" and "flex-control-paging".) I just had this same problem and I found that this  had a css width that extended beyond my content, thus adding white-space to the right.

I hope that's clear. Let me know if i can clarify.

Comment: I wish I could tell you. Unfortunately, this was almost a month ago, so I had to come up with a different solution and abandon Flexslider for that part altogether.

Thanks for the response, either way!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone running into this issue, several years on...

Just ensure that your child elements within the *Flexslider* haven't got padding or margins that would cause them to exceed in the expected width.

That is what causes an additional imaginary slide, as compensation.

```
.slide {
    margin: 0 !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
}
```